# Bash: how to cleanly log processed lines of ssh/ bash output?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, ssh, escaping

I wrote a linux bash script with tee and grep to *log and timestamp* the actions I take in my various ssh sessions. It works, but the logged lines are mixed together sometimes and are full of control characters. How can I properly escape control and other characters not visible in the original sessions and log each line separately?

I am learning bash and the linux interface, so any other suggestions to improve the script would be extremely welcome!

Here is my script (used as a wrapper for the ssh command):

```
#! /bin/bash
logfile=~/logs/ssh.log
desc="sshlog ${@}"
tab="\t"
format_line() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        echo -e "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")${tab}${desc}${tab}${line}"
    done
}
echo "[START]" | format_line >> ${logfile}
# grep is used to filter out command line output while keeping commands
ssh "$@" | tee >(grep -e '\@.*\:.*\$' --color=never --line-buffered | format_line >> ${logfile})
echo "[END]" | format_line >> ${logfile}
```

And here is a screenshot of the jarbled output in the log file:

[image]

**A note on the solution:** Tiago's answer took care of the nonprinting characters very well. Unfortunately, I just realized that the jumbling is being caused by backspaces and using the up and down keys for command completion. That is, the characters are being piped to grep as soon as they appear, and not line-by-line. I will have to ask about this in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462930/bash-duplicate-input-output-from-interactive-scripts-only-in-complete-lines-af).

**Update:** I [figured out a way to](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139876/37818) (almost always) handle up/down completion, backspace completion, and control characters.

Comment: I edited my answer with how to remove ANSI color chars, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove those characters with:

`perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'`

Not filtered:

```
perl -e 'for($i=0; $i<=255; $i++){print chr($i);}' | cat -A
^@^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H^I$
^K^L^M^N^O^P^Q^R^S^T^U^V^W^X^Y^Z^[^\^]^^^_ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~^?M-^@M-^AM-^BM-^CM-^DM-^EM-^FM-^GM-^HM-^IM-^JM-^KM-^LM-^MM-^NM-^OM-^PM-^QM-^RM-^SM-^TM-^UM-^VM-^WM-^XM-^YM-^ZM-^[M-^\M-^]M-^^M-^_M- M-!M-"M-#M-$M-%M-&M-'M-(M-)M-*M-+M-,M--M-.M-/M-0M-1M-2M-3M-4M-5M-6M-7M-8M-9M-:M-;M-<M-=M->M-?M-@M-AM-BM-CM-DM-EM-FM-GM-HM-IM-JM-KM-LM-MM-NM-OM-PM-QM-RM-SM-TM-UM-VM-WM-XM-YM-ZM-[M-\M-]M-^M-_M-`M-aM-bM-cM-dM-eM-fM-gM-hM-iM-jM-kM-lM-mM-nM-oM-pM-qM-rM-sM-tM-uM-vM-wM-xM-yM-zM-{M-|M-}M-~M-^?
```

Filtered:

```
perl -e 'for($i=0; $i<=255; $i++){print chr($i);}' | perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'  | cat -A
$
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~$
```

Explanation:

1. I am printing the whole ASCII table with:

   `perl -e 'for($i=0; $i<=255; $i++){print chr($i);}'`
2. I am identifying non printable chars with:

   `cat -A`
3. I am filtering non printable chars with:

   `perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'`

**Edit:**  It seems to me that you need to remove ANSI color chars:

Example:

```
 perl -MTerm::ANSIColor -e 'print colored("yellow on_magenta","yellow on_magenta"),"\n"'| sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" | perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:]]//g'
```

Adapting to your code:

```
format_line() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        line=$(sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" <<< "$line")
        line=$(perl -lpe 's/[^[:print:]]//g' <<< "$line")
        echo -e "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")${tab}${desc}${tab}${line}"
    done
}
```

I also edited your `grep` command:

```
ssh "$@" | tee >(grep -Po '(?<=\$).*' --color=never --line-buffered | format_line >> ${logfile})
```

Below the output of my test:

```
2014-06-26 10:11:10 +0100   sshlog tiago@localhost  [START]
2014-06-26 10:11:15 +0100   sshlog tiago@localhost  whoami
2014-06-26 10:11:16 +0100   sshlog tiago@localhost  exit
2014-06-26 10:11:16 +0100   sshlog tiago@localhost  [END]
```

Comment: This is much better, but the some lines are still getting merged together and there are now extra printable characters in the logs. Also, the timestamps are no longer in realtime (grep --line-buffered fixes it for grep).

Comment: Sample output (replace \n with line breaks):\n
2014-06-25 14:43:24 -0700 sshlog server [START]\n
2014-06-25 14:43:51 -0700 sshlog server [START]\n
2014-06-25 14:44:22 -0700 sshlog server [END]\n
2014-06-25 14:44:22 -0700 sshlog server ]0;user@server: ~user@server:~$ [K]0;user@server: ~user@server:~$ ls\n
2014-06-25 14:44:22 -0700 sshlog server ]0;user@server: ~user@server:~$ sudo su\n
2014-06-25 14:44:22 -0700 sshlog server ]0;user@server: ~user@server:~$ exit\n

Comment: Can you give a pastebin of the output?

Comment: I didn't see the "adapting to your code part". Trying it now.

Comment: Your solution inside the format_line() function works to keep timestamps current. I modified your filter with a similar one that seems to filter out the extra characters: http://pastebin.com/YQZjgyj9 . However, the lines are still getting jumbled together a lot.

Comment: With your original code, the output is like that in http://pastebin.com/5mfgDmJW . With my modifications, only a few extra letters get added to various parts of the logged command. I added examples of this to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I am starting to understand the problem: deleting and re-writing commands and command completion with the up and down keys are what is jumbling the words together and possibly creating the unexpected characters. Tee must be what is causing this issue. Do you have any suggestions for this, or would this be a better topic for a separate question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help; I am opening up a separate question for the backspace/ completion issue.

Answer (score 1):

While writing your own script is a great learning experience, you can also use [`script`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/script) to record everything printed on your terminal to a file.

The resulting file will still contains the control characters but there are multiple ways to get rid of them as described in [How to clean up output of linux 'script' command](https://superuser.com/q/236930/256451).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that I wouldn't know how to convert script to a timestamped log of commands like I do in my script. However, one of the answers seems to clean up my script output very well: "perl -pe 's/\e([^\[\]]|\[.*?[a-zA-Z]|\].*?\a)//g' | col -b". But this seems to be buffered so that my timestamps are no longer valid.

Comment: I figured out how to use the filter in realtime, but it still randomly adds characters to the logged commands. See examples at the bottom of my question.