# Bash: how to duplicate input/output from interactive scripts only in complete lines?

Tags: bash, ssh, io-redirection, tee

How can I capture the input/ output from a script in realtime (such as with tee), but line-by-line instead of character-by-character? My goal is to capture the input typed into the interactive prompts of a script only after backspaces and auto-completion have finished processing (after the RETURN key is hit).

Specifically, I am trying to create a wrapper script for ssh that creates a timestamped log of commands used on remote servers. [The script](http://pastebin.com/VdaKShX8), which uses tee to redirect the output for filtering, works well, but the redirected output gets jumbled with unsubmitted characters whenever I use the backspace key or the up/down keys to scroll through my remote history. For example: `service test stopexitservice test stopart` or `cd ..logs[1Pls -al`.

Perhaps there is a way to capture the terminal's scrollback and redirect that like with tee?

Update: I have found a [character-based cleanup solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/139876/37818) that does what I want most of the time. However, I am still hoping for an answer to this question (which may well be msw's answer that it is very difficult to do).

Comment: Try this answer from unix.stackexchange.com: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14684/removing-control-chars-including-console-codes-colours-from-script-output . However, you'd be better off using bash history on the remote machine.

Comment: Because I connect to so many different remote servers so frequently, I need an automated way of keeping the logs locally. One of the answers in your link handles backspace-erasing, but not up/down command completion, which results in a log such as `service test stopexitservice test stopart` when paging through commands `exit`, `service test stop`, and `service test start` (even if I do not actually use those commands). Thank you, though!

Comment: Create a new history file (with timestamps) for every login session. Make sure its updated frequently. Write a small crontask which moves the history files (with sftp) to your local repository. rsync can probably help. If necessary, write an ssh wrapper which records which remote machines you connected to (but then you have to avoid ssh from a remote machine.) Another option: use sshfs to keep the history files on your local machine.

Comment: This might be my only option, but I am still hoping for a local solution. The remote servers are mostly not managed by me, logins are often root or shared (non-production of course), and ssh sessions are often chained, so adjusting the history on all of them or even running automated downloads would be time-consuming and/ or impolite.

Comment: If my terminal displays the interactive prompt properly in its scrollback, shouldn't there be some way to parse that?

Comment: Anything is possible but parsing terminal controls is far from easy, and is even harder if you don't know the screen geometry. Of course, you can turn off terminal emulation so that you're using a dumb terminal, which is much easier to parse. But the user experience sucks. OTOH, if you're going to live with logging control characters, just use `script` or `tmux` or some such on your local machine; you don't need to clean the transcript in real time. (Unless you do :-)... but I've done lots of remote server management, and I never needed it.)

Comment: I actually do want to log in realtime because I want to timestamp each command :).

Comment: Put a timestamp in your prompt, then. (PS1) -- or figure out how to make it happen with bash history, which I still think is your best bet.

Comment: By the way, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418130/bash-how-to-cleanly-log-processed-lines-of-ssh-bash-output) told me how to escape control characters.

Comment: @Oleg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418130/bash-how-to-cleanly-log-processed-lines-of-ssh-bash-output is not enough as I elaborate in my answer.

Comment: Yes, the timestamp seems like an easier option than history download, thank you. If I can't find a local solution, I would use that. There are limitations: I have to figure out how to set (and unset) the remote variable automatically on ssh login, the prompt would be uncomfortably long, and it wouldn't handle chained ssh logins or "su" sessions. Still, this might be my best bet.

Comment: On second thought, remote timestamps would not avoid the problem of remote history download, since `script` logs the output of up/down completion as well and results in the same problem as before. Or were you thinking of some other non-realtime solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Unix world there are two primary modes of handling keyboard input. These are known as 'raw' in which characters are passed from the terminal to the reading program one at a time. This is the mode that editors (and such) will use because the editor needs to respond immediately when you press a key.

The other terminal discipline is called 'cooked' which is the line by line behavior that you think of as the bash line by line input where you get to backspace and the command is not executed until you press return. Ssh has to take your input in raw, character-by-character mode because it has no idea what is running on the other side. For example, if you are running  an editor on the far side, it can't wait for a return before sending the key-press. So, as some have suggested, grabbing shell history on the far side is the only reasonable way to get a command-by-command record of the bash commands you typed.

---

I oversimplified for clarity; actually most installations of bash take input in raw mode because they allow editor like command modification. For example, Ctrl-P scrolls up the command history or Ctrl-A goes to the beginning of the line. And bash needs to be able to get those keys the moment they are typed not waiting for a return.

This is another reason that capturing on the local side is obnoxiously difficult: if you capture on the local side, the stream will be filled with Backspaces and **all of bash's editing commands**. To get a true transcript of what the remote shell actually executed you have to parse the character stream as if you were the remote shell. There also a problem if you run something like

```
vi /some_file/which_is_on_the_remote/machine
```

the input stream to the local ssh will be filled with movement commands snippets of text including backspaces and so on and it would be bloody difficult to figure out what is part of a bash command and what is you talking to the editor.

Few things involving computers are impossible; getting clean input from the local side of an ssh invocation is really, really hard.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation. I'm thinking now that my best hope is to somehow capture the terminal scrollback. Is that just as difficult?

Comment: Would scrollback parsing be best asked as a separate question?

Comment: Accepted - I guess "there is no way" is the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I question the actual utility of recording the commands that you execute on a local or remote machine. The reason is that there is so much state which is not visible from a command log. As a simple example here's a log of two commands:

```
17:00$ cp important_file important_file.bak
17:15$ rm important_file
```

and two days later you are trying to figure out whether `important_file.bak` should have the contents you intended or not. Given that log you can't answer that simple question. Even if you had the sequence

```
16:58$ cat important_file
17:00$ cp important_file important_file.bak
17:15$ rm important_file
```

If you aren't capturing the output, the `cat` in the log will not tell you anything. Give me almost any command sequence and I can envision a scenario in which it will not give you the information you need to make sense of what was done.

Comment: Immediately, the purpose of the script is to have an approximate record of how I spend my time. 1) I have an automatic time-tracking system that I use for billing, and ssh sessions are currently resistant to logging. 2) It would be nice to tell my clients what I did with their servers (JUST IN CASE), even if they do not have proper logging set up on their end. At the very least, I think it is good practice in principle. You have a good point about the output, though. The script is limited to only certain uses.

Answer (score 0):

For a very similar purpose I use GNU `screen` which offer the option to record everything you do in a shell session (INPUT/OUTPUT). The log it creates also comes with undesirable characters but I clean them with perl:

`perl -ne 's/\x1b[[()=][;?0-9]*[0-9A-Za-z]?//g;s/\r//g;s/\007//g;print' < screenlog.0`

I hope this helps.

Some features of `screen`:
http://speaking-my-language.blogspot.com/2010/09/top-5-underused-gnu-screen-features.html

Site I found the perl-oneliner:
https://superuser.com/questions/99128/removing-the-escape-characters-from-gnu-screens-screenlog-n

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but screen seems to have the same problem with up/ down completion. I recorded a session with C-a H, paged up and down in my command history, and got the output: `test[2Plsasastest[K`. None of those commands were actually used in my session, just paged through.

Comment: I notice also that screen has a scrollback dump function, but how could the be harnessed to output line-by-line in realtime? Perhaps a diff between scrollbacks every second?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to insert you time stamp line-by-line, but you can dump a time stamp every minute: http://aperiodic.net/screen/commands:logtstamp